# How to modify an npm package built with TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I want to try and make some changes to a package published in npm? (I've suggest some changes as an issue but I think they are simple enough for me to attempt them).

https://www.npmjs.com/package/bt-presence#contributing--modifying

The author supplies some information on how to modify the package, but not really enough for someone doing it for the first time.

- Where should I clone the GitHub repo to?  The folder where the package is installed?  I tried it in my home folder and that would not build (unmodified).
- The command `npm run build` - where is this run from?  The root folder of the package where the `package.json` is?
- Will I need to modify the `package.json`?

In general what is the best way to develop something like this for npm?  I've worked on packages before but they were simply Javascript.

Comment: These instructions are specific to the `bt-presence` project. npmjs.com uses the README from the repository, so that text is just a copy of the README. Are you running into a specific error?

Comment: I am using it as an example - where would a git repository, that includes a TypeScript package, be cloned to, so that it could be built and where would that build command actually be run from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want to work on the `bt-presence` package in isolation, you can put the cloned repository anywhere.  If you want to use your modified version of `bt-presence` in combination with an application, my recommended approach is to register `bt-presence` as a dependency in the application's `package.json` file with the version set to a relative path to your `bt-presence` repository; then running `npm install` in the application will make a symlink from `node_modules/bt-presence` in the application to your `bt-presence` repository.
- `npm run build` should indeed be run from the root folder that contains the `package.json` of `bt-presence`.
- If you just want to change the code of `bt-presence`, you won't need to modify its `package.json`.  You would only modify the `package.json` if you need to change any of the settings in there, e.g, if you need to add additional dependencies to your version of `bt-presence`.

None of the above is really specific to TypeScript.  (Some JavaScript packages have build processes too if they need to transform or package the JavaScript files in some way.)

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'm using it with Node-Red and I'd like to use it as a replacement for the currently installed version while I test my changes.  As the installed version does not have the `ts` file, could I just insert that file in the right place in the installed versions folder? Is the `build` command from the **modules** `package.json` location or the applications?

Comment: First question: I don't recommend modifying an installed directory created by npm.  Instead add `"bt-presence": "path/to/bt-presence"` (replace with the actual relative path to your `bt-presence` repository) to the `dependencies` section of `package.json` in your application and then run `npm install`, and npm should make a symlink to your `bt-presence` repository so that Node-RED will use it.  Second question: the `bt-presence` `package.json` location (I updated the answer).

Comment: I am on this again Matt - Managed to clone and build a version of `bt-presence`. I can see where to add the dependency but a little nervous of running the `npm install` command.  Where exactly in relation to the `node-modules` folder should I run this? You mention `application` but this isn't really an application - just another module in `node-modules` that requires `bt-presence`. Do I just run the command in the folder where the `package.json` file resides that I have set the dependency?

Comment: I assume you have a top directory with a `package.json` file you created that specifies dependencies on `node-red` and `node-red-contrib-bt-presence`.  Add a relative-path dependency on `bt-presence` to this `package.json` file and run `npm install` in the top directory.  As long as the `bt-presence` version number is compatible, `node-red-contrib-bt-presence` will use your modified version of `bt-presence` without you having to edit `node_modules/node-red-contrib-bt-presence/package.json`.  Hopefully that does it; let me know if you need more help.